# What is a plane domain?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is a non-constant analytic function on a **plane domain** $\Omega$, then $f$ does not attain its maximum modulus at any point in $\Omega$.

Quick question: What is a plane domain? I know what a domain is but I can't find the definition for plane domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a domain (i.e. a connected open set) in the complex plane.